# Can I use simplesamlphp with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, simplesamlphp

I am using simplesamlphp to authenticate user on multiple domains from central login , But scenario is I have to use ajax to handle the login.

All was running good until flow comes to **postRedirect()** method in **SimpleSAML_Utilities** class which submit the form to assertion consumer url on service provider using javascript. Since ajax code can't handle javascript, flow stucks there and I got response as

[image]

My question is there any settings or customization in simplesaml php that can be used to handle this?